# Any good multi-threaded SFTP clients for Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, ftp, sftp

I am amazed that there doesn't seem to be a decent multiple connection capable FTP/SFTP client for Mac.

The only one I've seen is [CaptainFTP](http://captainftp.xdsnet.de), which looks awful, like it's from the last century.

There's also [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net), which is equally ancient, and not really set up as a browser, more of a download accelerator.

I've been using [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru), which is **amazing**, but CLI only, which makes it a pain.

Does anyone know of either (a) a "modern" client app which supports multiple connections, or (b) a GUI for `lftp`?

Comment: Have you looked at [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/)? Supports multiple connections, SFTP and WebDAV, Amazon S3..

Comment: Just tried it; but transfer capped out at 40 mbps. lftp gives me 100 mbps (the server limit.)

Comment: The only other recommend that I would have is [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org).

Comment: Filezilla maxed out at 30 mbps

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I found that [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) supports multiple connections. When transferring over SFTP, it's possible to select multiple connections in the upper-right of the progress dialog. Whether that has an effect on the total speed, I am currently not able to measure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out Fetch (http://fetchsoftworks.com) or Interarchy (https://nolobe.com/interarchy/)? They both allow simultaneous connections to multiple remote servers, remote-to-remote transfers, SFTP, and lots of other handy and solid features from long development histories with feedback from many users.

Comment: Tried both. Neither would go any faster than 20-25 mbps. And very uneven speed. lftp gives me consistent 100 mbps (limited by server internet bandwidth.)

Comment: Interesting - that's quite a difference. Does lftp achieve that through use of its ability to asynchronously issue multiple ftp commands? How does it do with just one large file?

Comment: I have no idea how, I just wish it had a GUI!

Answer (score 0):

Go get Transmit from Panic. It’s the gold standard in my opinion and experience. MountainDuck is my second choice (unless you can get along with the free Cyberduck)

- https://www.panic.com/transmit/
- https://mountainduck.io/