# Are there SFTP command-line tool for macOS that have history or auto complete?

Tags: macos, command-line, software-recommendation, ftp, sftp

Is there software for macOS that adds command history, autocompletion or other features to an `ftp` command line client?

Comment: Apple removed ftp as a command line utility some time ago. It was deprecated as an insecure protocol. I don't think anyone's made a command line replacement; though there are apps like Fetch, CyberDuck, etc. It might be helpful if you explained what you're trying to achieve by using command-line ftp in this way.

Comment: actually, I was testing sftp  ...but yeah, cyberduck, FZ are fine too

Answer (score 3):

FTP and SFTP are completely different protocols. There is software that supports both, but it's just a common interface over two completely different things under the hood.

### SFTP

#### SSHFS

The best way to use SFTP is via [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs), which makes any SFTP server available as a networked filesystem. You can then use ordinary shell commands (with the shell's history and completion) to access remote files.

```
mkdir myserver
sshfs myserver.example.com:/path/to/root example.com
ls myserver/subdir
cp myserver/subdir/myfile.txt ~
…
fusermount -u myserver
```

The sshfs software itself is easily available from package repositories such as Brew. The problem with sshfs is that it requires a kernel extension for [FUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io), which is fine on Intel Macs, but [a pain on Apple Silicon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412096/how-to-use-sshfs-on-apple-silicon-m1) due to the extra kernel integrity protections.

#### Improving the basic `sftp` command

You can use [`rlwrap`](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) to give any line-oriented command line software bash-like line editing commands, history, and completion of (local) file names. rlwrap is available from many package repositories including Brew.

### FTP

#### zftp

MacOS comes with a convenient command line FTP client: it's built into zsh, in the [zftp module](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zftp). You get all of zsh's features including command line history and completion (of both local and remote files). FTP commands can be used by prefixing either `zftp`  (e.g. `zftp open`, `zftp ls`, …) or just `zf` (e.g. `zfopen`, `zfls`, …).

```
zmodload zsh/zftp
zfopen ftp.example.com
zfls
zfget myfile.txt
zfclose
```

Comment: Woah - zsh embedding zmodload for easy install of zftp is a nice tip. +thanks

Answer (score 1):

I’m all in to use [Mountain Duck](https://mountainduck.io/) and [Transmit](https://www.panic.com/transmit/) for my **ftp** needs now that macOS does not ship ftp or telnet or other “vintage” and traditional command line tools. If you’re not into paid, supported software, check out Cyberduck.

If you only need command line ftp and don’t want to compile it yourself, go for [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install  **tnftp**

```
brew install tnftp
```

- https://osxdaily.com/2018/08/07/get-install-ftp-mac-os/

If you might need other tools, the **inetutils** is a nice option. Also since sftp and ftps are different protocols with similar names, [this other Q&A may be helpful.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/169105/5472)

Comment: Just in case: for FTP transfer, macOS ships with curl command line tool - which has always been a better option than ftp tool.